# Power with varible resistance

Tags: electricity

I know that P=VI, but what i was thinking about is that if we kept the voltage constant and increased the resistance, we will have less energy consumed by the resistance per second. So, this seems illogical to me; in my opinion, as we increase the resistance, more collisions will happen. Therefore, more energy is released.
So, how more resistance less power?????

Comment: As kw_artem said, increasing R also has the effect of decreasing the current I, so the power P actually decreases. On the other hand, if you are considering the situation where the resistance R is connected to a constant-current circuit, then the power P (=R*I^2) will increase as the resistance R increases. In other words, your logic is correct if you assume that the flow of electrical current (I) is kept constant.

Comment: But isn't less electrons with high energy like many electrons with less energy??

Answer (score 0):

Two governing equations here:

$$\frac VR=I\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad P=VI$$

Put them together and you get:

$$P=RII=RI^2$$

Now you increase the resistance - as a general example, you could make it $k$ times bigger: $R_{new}=k R$. Larger resistance to the charge flow of course *reduces* the charge flow, so the current is reduced:

$$I_{new}=\frac V{R_{new}}=\frac V{kR}=\frac1k \frac VR=\frac1k I$$

So doubling the resistance apparently halfs the current for us to keep the voltage. But what does it do to the power?

$$P_{new}=R_{new}I_{new}^2=(kR)(\frac1kI)^2=kR\frac1{k^2}I^2=\frac1kRI^2=\frac1kP$$

So apparently the power is halfed and thereby decreased for increasing resistance. We could also quickly have reached this without considering the current, by using:

$$P=VI=V\frac VR=\frac{V^2}R \text{ and new power will be: }\\
P_{new}=\frac{V^2}{R_{new}}=\frac{V^2}{kR}=\frac1k\frac{V^2}R=\frac1k P $$

Comment: I was looking for a logical explanation without math but thanks anyway